# Selecting Text Field in VB.NET by MouseDrag

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a text field and I cannot drag my mouse and select the value/text within the text field in a vb.net application [The cursor is stuck in the front of the text](http://pasteboard.co/131EXuT5.png). However, just to check, I created another 'test' application containing a text field, and the mouse function is working fine. [Mouse can be easily dragged to select the text field](http://pasteboard.co/131yBXOg.png). I am completely lost here and any help in this subject matter would be really appreciated. I am wondering whether the fault lies with the application in itself.

> Note: I have simply dragged and dropped a text-box from the toolbox of
>   visual studio and obtained those results. No special code written

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to share your code where it is working and where it is not working so as to get better help!

Comment: I am just dragging a text box from the toolbox and writing a demo text and it is not working

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share your attempt of working and non working code. Else it would be a theory.

Comment: http://pasteboard.co/131yBXOg.png

http://pasteboard.co/131EXuT5.png

Comment: First Image of 'This is a Test', contains the mouse drag function, which is working. The fact is there is no code associated with it. It is just a simple drag of text-box from toolbox of visual studio. The second is the same, but if you carefully notice the cursor position, which is always fixed at the start of the text. I cannot drag it to select it. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check and set the TextBox's Enabled property to True

Comment: Read the question again, OP wants to select the text on mouse drag.

Comment: It is enabled. I have checked the properties. I can use the right and left key to edit but not the mouse function to drag and select the text within that particular text field

Comment: @RahulTripathi useful comment. Thanks.